# How to find the files of a certain extension with the same exact size?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

In Windows, if I have a folder with many subfolders and files of some extension, I need a command to give it the file extension, then it searches for this specific extension through all the subfolders while grouping the files of the same exact size.

Comment: take a look at  `Get-help Get-ChildItem` and the `-Filter`, the `-File`, and  `-Recurse` parameters of that cmdlet.

Comment: It might be helpful to expand on what you intend to do with these files. There are few different applications for file deduplication if that's your goal. Also, to be clear, you want to specify an extension then find any files with that extension that are the exact same size? So if the extension is e.g. `.txt` and `A.txt`, `B.txt` and `C.txt` are all the same size, they should be a match as a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be specific without knowing what you are trying to do.  Here  is a code block that might get you started.

```
get-childitem $HOME -recurse -filter "*.ps1" |
  group-object length |
  sort-object count -desc
```

This illustrates using the -recurse and -filter parameters to get a lot of files with the same extension, in this case .ps1.  It then creates groups of files that have the same length.  All files with length 1024 will end up in the same group.  It  then sorts these groups by descending hit count.

From here, you will need to learn how to work on one group at a time, and how to unpack the files from a given group.

Comment: How to change `$Home` to reflect the current folder and its subfolders? As your answer makes the search take place all over the hard disk or partition C probably.

Comment: Use can refer to the current folder with a dot.

Comment: May I know what the command is to change the current directory of PS ISE to that of the executed script?

Comment: @Diaa - take a look at `$PSScriptRoot` ... [*grin*]